# JS Scrolling happens before page is ready

Tags: javascript, ajax, scroll

I have a script that updates a div (`chat-area`) by appending text using ajax. It then scrolls to the bottom of the div once updated. The only way I can get the div to scroll to the bottom (and stay at the bottom) is by using "`setTimeout`". However, that creates a terrible effect.

What I want:
The div `chat-area` should stay scrolled to the bottom after any change. (without any delay)

How might I accomplish this?

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            <!-- RUN WHEN USER CLICKS CHAT -->
                $('#chatform').submit(function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                    <!-- Updates Window -->
                    var f = document.forms.e_form;
                    var userinput = f.e_input.value;
                        $.ajax({ url: 'path/file.php',
                         data: {action: 'test', theinput: userinput},
                         type: 'post',
                         success: function(output) {
                                    $("#chat-area").append(output);
                                }
                    });
                <!--  Resets and scrolls form -->
                            $('#chattextbox').val("");
                            $("#chattextbox").focus();
                             setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById('chat-area').scrollTop = document.getElementById('chat-area').scrollHeight;
    }, 200);

                }); 
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your cleanup code in a `complete` callback.  See [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var scrollDown = (function(){
    document.getElementById('chat-area').scrollTop = 
      document.getElementById('chat-area').scrollHeight;
  });
  /* RUN WHEN USER CLICKS CHAT */
  $('#chatform').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    /* Updates Window */
    var f = document.forms.e_form;
    var userinput = f.e_input.value;
    $.ajax({
      url: 'path/file.php',
      data: {action: 'test', theinput: userinput},
      type: 'post',
      success: function(output) {
        $("#chat-area").append(output);
      },
      complete: function() {
        /* Resets and scrolls form */
        $('#chattextbox').val("");
        $("#chattextbox").focus();
        scrollDown();
      }
    });
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should scroll the page once you update the chat-area content on ajax success.

```
success: function(output) {
 $("#chat-area").append(output);
 document.getElementById('chat-area').scrollTop = document.getElementById('chat-area').scrollHeight;
}
```

No need to use `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 0):

Put your scrolling code into a function and call this function after you appended the text you received via ajax. I haven't tried it, but something similar to this should work:

```
    // Methode for reseting and refocus Input-Field
function resetAndFocusInput($target){
  $target.val("");
  $target.focus();
}
// Methode for scrolling to top of chat area
function scrollTo($target){
  $target.scrollTop($target.scrollHeight())
}
$( document ).read(function(){
  var $chatform = $( '#chatform' ),
  $userInput = $( '#chattextbox' ),
  $chatArea = $( "#chat-area" );
  // Bind to submit-event of chat-form
  $chatform.on( 'submit', function( event ){
    event.preventDefault();
    // Receive chat-data via ajax and update chat-area on success
      $.ajax({ url: 'path/file.php',
        data: {action: 'test', theinput: $userInput.val() },
        type: 'post',
        success: function( data ) {
              $chatArea.append( data );
              scrollTo( $chatArea );
        },
        complete: function(){
            resetAndFocusInput( $userInput );
        }
    });
  });
});
```